# Configure logging in AWS Step Functions Local

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-step-functions

I am using [AWS Step Functions Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-docker.html) for testing Step Functions on my local machine, but the level of logging has significantly increased the time for my test suite to run. I cannot find any configuration options on the AWS website to control the log level so I have been trying to roll my own with no success.

The logging I am trying to hide looks like this:

```
2022-12-15 12:11:36.562: CreateStateMachine => {"requestClientOptions":{"readLimit":131073,"skipAppendUriPath":false},"requestMetricCollector":null,"customRequestHeaders":null,"customQueryParameters":null,"cloneSource":null,"sdkRequestTimeout":null,"sdkClientExecutionTimeout":null,"name":"<MY STEP FUNCTION NAME","definition":"{MY STEP FUNCTION DEFINITION}"...}

2022-12-15 12:11:36.782: [200] CreateStateMachine <= {"sdkResponseMetadata":null,"sdkHttpMetadata":null,"stateMachineArn":"arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789012:stateMachine:MY_STEP_FUNCTION_NAME","creationDate":1671106296763}
```

I downloaded the [Zip file containing the Step Functions Local JAR file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-jar.html), extracted the zip file, extracted `StepFunctionsLocal.jar`, and found there was a `log4j.properties` file. "Excellent!", I thought, I can provide my own configuration file and it will be great. So I created a Docker image with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11

WORKDIR /jar
COPY . /jar

RUN yum -y install unzip zip && yum -y clean all && rm -rf /var/cache

RUN mkdir -p /jar/extracted
RUN unzip StepFunctionsLocal.zip -d /jar/extracted

ENV SFN_MOCK_CONFIG=""
ENV LAMBDA_ENDPOINT=""
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=""

EXPOSE 8083

CMD ["java", "-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/jar/log4j.properties", "-jar", "/jar/extracted/StepFunctionsLocal.jar"]
```

With the following `log4.properties` file which is in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`:

```
 # console is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
 log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

 # console uses PatternLayout.
 log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

 log4j.appender.APPLOG=amazon.platform.logging.PeriodicConcurrentFileAppender
 log4j.appender.APPLOG.layout=amazon.platform.logging.SanitizingPatternLayout
 log4j.appender.APPLOG.File=../logs/application.log

 log4j.appender.APPLOG.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
 log4j.appender.APPLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %d{D/HH:mm:ss:SSS} %t %c - %m%n


 # Set root logger level to INFO and its only appender to console.
 log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, APPLOG

 #log4j.logger.com.amazon.coral.reflect=WARN
 #log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=OFF
 # Enable this to see everything that httpclient does.
 #log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=WARN
 #log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
 #log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
 #log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.swf.console=ERROR
 #log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.console.auth=ERROR
```

This is the same file I found in the extracted `StepFunctionsLocal.jar` except all of the lines which configure the log level have been commented out and the root logger level set to `ERROR`.

I built the image and ran it, but the same logging still appeared. At this point I'm stumped. Am I going about this the right way? Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Search for `CreateStateMachine` within all files in the extracted JAR and see which logger its using - there may be more than one logger configured in the Java application or it may be writing to the console.